# Excel: eliminating redundant, 'middleman' cells

Tags: excel

I've tried searching around for this, but it seems that I have not managed to find the right wording.  As a minimal example, imagine I had three cells with the following formulas:

```
A1:  =2
B1:  =A1*2
C1:  =SQRT(B1)
```

Since B1 only serves as an interim step in a calculation which starts at A1 and ends at C1, I'm looking for an automatic way to replace the formula in C1 with one that eliminates the need for B1:

```
C1: =SQRT(A1*2)
```

The exact problem I'm facing simply involves this idea with a large 2D array of these 'middleman' cells, which only has two actual input values.  Since it is 2D, this is making producing output graphs cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in VBA you could do it this way, i use the cell D1 that you can watch the result.

```
Sub MergeCellFormula()
    Dim sB1 As String: sB1 = Mid(Cells(1, 2).Formula, 2)
    Dim sC1 As String: sC1 = Cells(1, 3).Formula
    Cells(1, 4) = Replace(sC1, "B1", sB1)
End Sub
```

regards